# Parameters and arguments. How do I return the sentence with all the items in the array?

Tags: javascript

If I pass in "largest countries" as an argument, I want it to return the respective string in the condition and all the countries in this array ["China", "India", "USA"].

If I pass in "best fruits" as an argument, I want it to return the respective string in the condition and all the fruits in this array ["Apples", "Bananas"].

My code doesn't do that. It returns just one country, the first one or just one fruit, the first one. How do i get it to return all the items in the respective arrays?

```js
let sentenceC = document.getElementById("constructed")

function generateSentence(desc, arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (desc === "largest countries") {
      return `The 3 ${desc} are ${arr[i]},  `
    } else if (desc === "best fruits") {
      return `The 2 ${desc} are ${arr[i]}, `
    }
  }
}
sentenceC.innerHTML = generateSentence("largest countries", ["China", "India", "USA"])
```

```html
<p id="constructed"></p>
```

Comment: The reason is that once you have found a matched result,you invoke `return`,thus it will return only one record

Comment: Why will using return only bring one record? Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop at all, and can just use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the array values into a string.  For example:

```js
let sentenceC = document.getElementById("constructed")

function generateSentence(desc, arr) {
  if (desc === "largest countries") {
    return `The 3 ${desc} are ${arr.join(', ')}`
  } else if (desc === "best fruits") {
    return `The 2 ${desc} are ${arr.join(', ')}`
  }
}
sentenceC.innerHTML = generateSentence("largest countries", ["China", "India", "USA"])
```

```html
<p id="constructed"></p>
```

You can even improve it by not hard-coding the lengths in your string and using the actual array length provided, which means you don't even need the `if` condition:

```js
let sentenceC = document.getElementById("constructed")

function generateSentence(desc, arr) {
  return `The ${arr.length} ${desc} are ${arr.join(', ')}`
}
sentenceC.innerHTML = generateSentence("largest countries", ["China", "India", "USA"])
```

```html
<p id="constructed"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use for, just use join like bellow:

```js
function generateSentence(desc, arr){
        if(desc === "largest countries"){
            return `The 3 ${desc} are ${arr.join(",")},  `
        } else if (desc === "best fruits"){
            return `The 2 ${desc} are ${arr.join(",")}, `
        }
}
```